# call array function from a class to main class

Tags: c#, function, class

I'm trying to write a program to allow the user to choose a number of students and then asked him to enter their grads. so that I will create `public int numberOfStu=0` to storage number of student and `public double [] grad` to save grades in a class called `grade`.
I have two problems:
1- I can't make the length of `grad` is the same value of `numberOfStu`
this is my code:

```
class grade
{
     public int numberOfStu=0 ;
    double[] grad = new double [numberOfStu]; // here is error

    public grade()
    { }
    public grade(int numStu, double [] Grads){
        numberOfStu = numStu;
        grad = Grads;
    }
    public int number() {
        Console.Write("enter number of student:");
        return numberOfStu = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public double [] Gread(int numberOfStu) {
        for (int i=0 ; i< numberOfStu; i++) {
            grad[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        return grad;
    }
    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of students are {0}", numberOfStu);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStu; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Gread of studen {0} is {1}", i + 1, Gread[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

2- I don't know how i can call `Gread` function in main class throw it array function.
This is main code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        grade gread1 = new grade();
        gread1.number();

        gread1.Grad(gread1.number()); //here is error
        gread1.print();
    }
```

Comment: An array can't be of size `0`  - that is what the error means.

Comment: What are the errors? Have you already tried searching for solutions to the errors?

Comment: Use an Arraylist<double> instead of double[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this a little refactored:

```
public class Grades
{

  private double[] _Items;

  public int Count
  {
    get
    {
      return _Items.Length;
    }
  }

  public Grades()
  {
  }

  public Grades(double[] grades)
  {
    _Items = grades;
  }

  public int Resize()
  {
    Console.Write("Enter number of students:");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int count);
    if ( _Items == null )
      _Items = new double[count];
    else
      Array.Resize(ref _Items, count);
    return Count;
  }

  public double[] Initialize(int count)
  {
    if ( _Items == null )
      _Items = new double[count];
    else
      Array.Resize(ref _Items, count);
    for ( int i = 0; i < _Items.Length; i++ )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter grade of student {0}:", i + 1);
      double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out _Items[i]);
    }
    return _Items;
  }

  public void Print()
  {
    if ( _Items == null )
      Console.WriteLine("There is no students.");
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Number of students are {0}", _Items.Length);
      for ( int i = 0; i < _Items.Length; i++ )
        Console.WriteLine("Grade of student {0} is {1}", i + 1, _Items[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

```
static void Test()
{
  var g = new Grades();
  g.Initialize(5);
  g.Print();
}
```

Result:

```
Enter grade of student 1:
1
Enter grade of student 2:
2
Enter grade of student 3:
3
Enter grade of student 4:
4
Enter grade of student 5:
5
```

```
Number of students are 5
Grade of student 1 is 1
Grade of student 2 is 2
Grade of student 3 is 3
Grade of student 4 is 4
Grade of student 5 is 5
```

You may rename `Grades` to `Students` and `_Items` to `_Grades`.

Comment: You are used some of strange codes but I'm interesting about them.. I learned many things by you.. thank you for your help :)